# jplayer not showing playlist in IE

Tags: jquery, jplayer

Can anyone tell me why the jQuery player I have here works great in FF and Chrome, but doesn't show the playlist in IE?

http://374designs.com/adaville/media-player.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery Player straightly on your site,use the media player based on jQuery player mentioned in following url...

http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/html5-music-player-updated/

Comment: I'm attempting to configure your player (it is very nice looking, by the way), but when I add a second track in the js playlist file, all of the content disappears.

Comment: Nevermind. I was missing a comma in between the {bracketed info}

Comment: I've updated to your player. Looks great in Chrome & FF, but doesn't work for me in IE 8.
http://374designs.com/adaville/media/index.html

Comment: Since Jplayer provides Flash Fallback For IE,Follow the steps in given url to make it work in ie  http://superuser.com/questions/5634/how-to-enable-the-flash-player-plugin-in-ie8